# Ubuntu 16.10 DNS client does not use A record when AAAA returns SERVFAIL

Tags: networking, dns

A record exists, AAAA returns SERVFAIL, host has dual stack connectivity

```
$ host www.fidelityrewards.com
www.fidelityrewards.com has address 170.135.184.45
Host www.fidelityrewards.com not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

Ubuntu 16.10 does not connect via IPv4

```
$ wget www.fidelityrewards.com
--2017-02-27 07:41:57--  http://www.fidelityrewards.com/
Resolving www.fidelityrewards.com (www.fidelityrewards.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘www.fidelityrewards.com
```

working correctly on dual stack Debian 8.7

```
$ wget www.fidelityrewards.com
--2017-02-27 08:44:47--  http://www.fidelityrewards.com/
Resolving www.fidelityrewards.com (www.fidelityrewards.com)... 170.135.184.45
Connecting to www.fidelityrewards.com (www.fidelityrewards.com)|170.135.184.45|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2363 (2.3K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.1’

index.html.1          100%[=========================>]   2.31K  --.-KB/s   in 0s     

2017-02-27 08:44:50 (143 MB/s) - ‘index.html.1’ saved [2363/2363]
```

Which component should I file a bug against? glibc?

Edit:
/etc/nsswitch.conf

```
hosts:          files myhostname mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns wins 
networks:       files
```

Comment: What does `/etc/nsswitch.conf` contain?

Comment: updated in question

Comment: If you remove `resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] ` from that list, does the problem persist?

Comment: I changed it to `hosts:          files dns` and it fixed the problem. What is the difference between resolve and dns?

Comment: I'm not very sure, but `resolve` should be provided by the package [`libnss-resolve`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libnss-resolve) (aka `systemd-resolved`), and `dns` by glibc. IOW the bug is in systemd.

Comment: It works on 16.10 here. However, I suspect the problem is with the domain's DNS anyway; if no AAAA record is present it should return NOERROR with an empty answer, not SERVFAIL.

Comment: Compare, e.g., with `www.twitter.com`, which also has no AAAA but is properly configured.

Comment: with `hosts: files dns` in nsswitch.conf, it looks like systemd-resolved still does caching. But `dns` is provided by glibc?